# How to verify email addresses for ecommerce sites?

Tags: validation, email, authentication, e-commerce, email-validation

I am in the process of building an ecommerce site and thought i'd put a post on here to see how you guys deal with email verification (which is something I debate every time I build something with ecommerce!) Obviously the standard way to deal with it is to send a verification email to the user after registration and they have to click on the link within the email to activate their account. Generally with ecommerce solutions I allow users to sign up and make their purchase without having verified their email (so as not to send them away from the checkout). They are not however able to login to their account again until they have verified their email address by clicking the link in the email. In theory this is fine but it always worries me as what if someone can't verify it (eg it's in their SPAM folder which they haven't checked, the email has been blocked for some reason etc). This means when they return they can't login and they have to contact the site admin to activate their account (which many people won't do).

The only alternatives i can see are to either not verify the emails at all which seems like a dodgy thing to do or allow all users to login whether they've verified their email or not but only send email notifications/newsletters etc if their address has been verified. The first option is obviously not ideal, the second one isn't bad but you obviously want to send confirmation emails after purchase etc to users and this makes it less likely this will happen. Perhaps the best way is to allow all users to login whatever their status and (if their address isn't verified) show them a big message after login saying 'You have not yet verified your email, until this is completed you will not receive any order confirmations or other notifications' (or something more succinct!)

What do you guys reckon?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I frequently see that a shop allows two types of orders. In the first I do not have to register or login. I just enter name, address, phone number, maybe even e-mail address. But in this case of course I do not get automatic notifications, especially not newsletter. The other way is to login at least before completing the order.

To summarize, the registration always requires confirmation, but the registration itself is optional. I think this is the best model, but there is no single ideal solution, you have to have a compromise.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you are selling low cost impuls-buy goods or services, why not make registering obligatory. But make it very simple, and avoid the double opt in problems: Just ask new clients to register by emailing their vcard to your website, from their primary email. After that they can choose a password and extend/edit their profile. Or you could have people log in using janrain or another service (using the login credentials from a verified account used on another website) Unless you find that clients rather not have their google/facebook accounts linked to ecommerce sites...

Comment: I don't think the premise of getting users to email in to register is a good idea, this will take them away from the site when they are in the process of purchasing (or require them to do it at a later stage which most won't do) which is generally a bad thing for ecommerce sites. I agree with the login of using another login service but as you say this is potentially a problem as users may not want these accounts associated.